# How to float an image with inline-block?

Tags: html, css

I want to use inline-block to have an image and on the right of it a text. But it does not work, what is wrong?

[js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0v9rtug2/)

HTML

```
<img src="http://i0.gmx.net/images/684/19209684,pd=2,h=250,mxh=600,mxw=800,w=480.jpg" width="120" />
<article>
    <h4> Title</h4>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren.</p>
</article>
```

CSS

```
img, article{
     display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried going old school with an `align="right"` on the `<img>`

Comment: `article` is using `width: auto` in this case its `100%` so its pushing down to the next line. [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/0v9rtug2/4/) here is a demo with a width on `article`. (thats the problem with them not sitting side by side anyways)

Comment: Why cling on to inline-block here, when this is the perfect use for float? It doesn't make sense.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/0v9rtug2/5/

Comment: @ralph.m because inline-block needs no clear afterwards!

Comment: You don't need any clearing, though. Just float the image, and not the article. If you don't want the article to wrap under the image, set it to overflow: hidden.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you give `article` a specific width it wont work because the content of the article flows the entire page

```
article{
    width:300px;
}
```

Check This **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/benjaminthomas/0v9rtug2/3/)**

Answer (score 1):

When you float an element, it's display property gets treated and set as block anyway. You would need to set the container to display: inline-block to create a new block formatting context that doesn't need a clearing element. (There are also other methods for this.) See here:

[image]

To the left are the styles I have set, to the right are the computed styles for that same element. Notice the display properties.

You must create a new block formatting context for the container by setting, overflow: hidden; or display:inline-block; or by floating the container (not the best solution).

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because the width of both elements when added together exceeds 100%, thus the `article` element is forced onto a new line. A simple fix to this is to wrap the elements in a new element set to display as "table", setting the `img` and `article` elements to display as "table-cell":

```
<section>
    <img ... />
    <article>...</article>
</section>
```

```css
section {
    display: table;
}

img, article{
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

[**JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/JamesD/0v9rtug2/6/).

Answer (score 0):

You can float the image and set the article to `overflow: hidden` if you don't want it to wrap under the image: http://codepen.io/pageaffairs/pen/HAjfE

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

img {float: left; margin-right: 10px;}
article {overflow: hidden;}
h4 {margin-top: 0;}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<img src="http://i0.gmx.net/images/684/19209684,pd=2,h=250,mxh=600,mxw=800,w=480.jpg" width="120" />
<article>
    <h4> Title</h4>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren.</p>
</article>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Can be your image inside Article?

You can put your image inside P tag in article and use float css.

```
<article>
    <h4> Title</h4>
    <p>
        <img src="http://i0.gmx.net/images/684/19209684,pd=2,h=250,mxh=600,mxw=800,w=480.jpg" width="120" />
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren.
    </p>
</article>

img, article{
    display: inline-block;
}
img { float: right; }
```